# Yeshivas that relocated

Tags: history, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, yeshiva-school

BS"D

Which yeshivot relocated throughout the 20th century due to war, pogroms, etc.?

For example, I know that [The Mir Yeshiva moved to Shanghai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_Yeshiva_(Belarus)) in 1941.

Are there any other similar yeshivot?

Do any of them exist today (like in Eretz Yisrael)?

**Please provide sources for your answers.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. **[Slabodka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivas_Knesses_Yisrael_(Slabodka))** Yeshiva was originally in Lithuania and after the ravages of WWI and enforced military conscription in the years that followed, they established a branch in Chevron in 1924. Following the Chevron Massacre they then moved again to Yerushalayim.
2. **[Ponovezh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponevezh_Yeshiva)** Yeshiva was founded in 1908 and was also originally located in Lithuania. It moved to Bnei Brak in 1944.
3. **[Telz/Telshe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telshe_Yeshiva)** Yeshiva was originally in the town of Telz, Lithuania. During the Holocaust, Rabbis Elya Meir Bloch and Chaim Mordechai Katz were on a fund-raising mission in America and realised that their only option to ensure the continuity of the Yeshiva was to relocate the whole yeshiva to Cleveland, Ohio.

---

**EDIT**

There is a good list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_yeshivos_in_Europe_(before_World_War_II)) which includes in addition to the ones above:

4. [Grodno Yeshiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grodno_Yeshiva) moved from Grodno, Belarus to New York
5. [Kaminetz Yeshiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivas_Knesses_Beis_Yitzchak-Kaminetz) moved multiple times within Europe and re-established in Yerushalayim in 1924
6. [Kesser Torah Radomsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keser_Torah_Radomsk) (a network of chassidish yeshivos) - re-established as a Kollel in Bnei Brak in the 1940s and since opened in Yerushalayim, Lakewood and Montreal
7. [Lomza Yeshiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lomza_Yeshiva) - established a new branch in Petach Tikva
8. [Yeshivas Chachmei Lublin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chachmei_Lublin_Yeshiva#Re-establishment_in_Bnei_Brak) - Re-established in Bnei Brak by Rabbi Shmuel Wosner zt"l
9. [Novardok Yeshiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novardok_Yeshiva) - Grew and added many branches throughout Poland and Lithuania. Destroyed during World War II, Rabbi Yoffen reopened it New York
10. [Pressburg Yeshiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressburg_Yeshiva_(Austria-Hungary)) - re-established in Israel after Hitler's invasion of Czechoslovakia
11. [Ramailes Yeshiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramailes_Yeshiva) - Based in Lithuania. After WWII, Rabbi Yisrael Zev Gustman, who had taught in the yeshiva the war, re-established it in New York City and later in Israel
12. Slonim Yeshiva - In 1941, Rabbi Yagel fled war-torn Europe and reestablished the yeshiva in Ramat Gan
13. Frankfurt Yeshiva - The yeshiva closed after the rise of Nazism in the country, and a short time after, Rabbi Breuer escaped and settled in America where he opened Yeshiva Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch

Comment: @GershonGold - you literally beat me by a second with Slabodka!

Comment: @JoelK I am referring to Yeshivas Knesses Yisrael there was a split. The yeshiva in Lithuania was destroyed during the Holocaust, and re-established by Rabbi Sher in Bnei Brak.

Comment: @Dov As an aside, YKY split again later on - Chevron Geulah remained (in the original Yerushalayim location?) and YKY Chevron moved to Giv’at Mordechai.

Comment: Thanks both for the clarity!

Comment: (9). Gateshead Yeshiva = Novardok

Comment: Good shout @GRAPKE!

Comment: Per the Feldheim biography of R' Breuer זצ"ל, Yeshivas R' Samson Raphael Hirsch is not a continuation of the Frankfurt Lehrenstalt (Jeschiwo), rather it was established as a new TIDE-affiliated school for Jekkisch children in his kehilloh. Neither is the Beis Midrash 'al shem R' Shlomo Breuer, which was established at R' Schwab's insistence, although this would be closer to the Lehrenstalt than YSRH

Comment: @TheGRAPKE, it's more of a daughter institution than a re-establishment. Actually, my grandfather learned there for a few weeks in 1939, but his Neo-Orthodox upbringing couldn't acclimate to the yeshivish lifestyle, since listening to the radio and reading German papers was permissible in the IRG, whereas English papers and radio were banned in Gateshead, nonetheless, that education visa to the UK may have saved his life !

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt All Novardok yeshivos are daughter institutions.

Comment: @JoelK I edited the Slabodka entry :-)